# Error in pyspark command line in case of Hive-S3 table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

I have a Hive table (sourced by a S3 bucket) that works on Hive shell like a charm.
I wanted to continue with pyspark. I can access HDFS table from pyspark shell but when I want to access my data in the S3 I receive this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 380, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.showString.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3ARetryPolicy.<init>(S3ARetryPolicy.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could someone help me how I shall resolve that?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` type of errors almost always caused by version differences between a client and cluster.

Comment: I am trying to switch spark from 2.7.1 to 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck on that `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration` error for weeks!

The `spark-submit` and `pyspark` executables that come with `pip install pyspark` seem to be broken.

I downloaded the pre-built version from the [Spark download site](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html), extracted the tarball and voilá, it works!

I tested it with the following:

- OS: Ubuntu and Amazon Linux 2
- Java: OpenJDK 8 and OpenJDK 11 and Amazon Corretto 11
- Python: 3.6 and 3.7
- Spark: 3.0.0 pre-built for Hadoop 3.2

In all cases I got the same error when using the `spark-submit` and `pyspark` executables that come with pip.
In all cases the error disappeared when I used the spark executables that come with the downloaded tarball.

Just make sure to set these variables (your values will be different of course):

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/Spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/opt/Spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/conf
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and launch your spark-submit / pyspark with: `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.816,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.2.0`